# How to bookmark a URL in Google Chrome via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to bookmark a URL in Chrome using JavaScript. I have done for other browsers. But I don't have any solution for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome does not actually let you add bookmarks via Javascript**

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/chrome/Wm-UHqaBEbI/Ukiwm46v3BsJ

Comment: Any alternative solution ?